# Random drop in rpm during clutch down

Tags: rpm

I am using Hyundai Grand i10 petrol car.
Recently i got fit CNG in my car. After CNG fitted i am facing a problem of random engine off at any gear when i pressed clutch. But it only happened if i run my car at CNG and never happened at petrol. Sparks plug, throttle body clean and engine scanning, car service(Engineoil, coolant, gearoil, filter etc..) done but nothing happened. Also all type of CNG celebrations setting did but still same problem.
Last find out is this when i pressed the clutch then rpm start dropping till 200 not every time. When it goes to down engine off at CNG.
RPM also goes down at petrol but engine never off.

Me and my CNG fitment center person both are clue less. What next to do...
We also tries to cng parts but no effects.

Your help is always appreciable and will be thankful to you.

Regards:
Vineet Goel

Comment: Have you checked all the electrical connections to the sensors - sounds like you have been disconnecting just about all that exists...

Comment: I have not checked the electrical connection but i have noticed that RMP also dropped at petrol but engine never lose power at pertol. RMP dropped till 400 than recover at petrol while it not happen at CNG. and Engine losed power